# Videoconferencing app with ability to locally mute participant (mute for me)

Tags: video-conferencing

We are looking for a videoconferencing app that has one specific feature:

Ability to mute participant, but only for myself so others can still hear them.

The use case is that if two participants join the conference from one physical room they can hear themselves twice, usually with delay, which makes conversation near impossible.

Is there such an app?

Other nice to have features we would like in the app:

- Share conversation with simple link (i.e. no registration needed)
- Working from the browser (i.e. no complex installation needed)
- Screen sharing

Comment: Welcome Josef!  If you have any OS or price requirements (or guidelines), please add them to your question.  Thanks, and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible with all tools that use the WebRTC technologies build into all modern web browsers.  Question is if you are willing to pay the cost.

The solution I would choose is to use [janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) as backend "mixer" service, and [Jangouts](https://github.com/jangouts/jangouts) as web frontend, and then (yourself or pay someone else) adapt Janus' videoroom plugin to keep audio as separate streams (*not* mix them together), and adapt Jangouts to support silencing others (not only yourself).

Reason that you are unlikely to find this feature in turnkey solutions is that it is an uncommon tradeoff:

Internet-based realtime video conferencing is a balancing act among multiple factors.  Modern web-browsers have a built-in support for video-conferencing called `WebRTC`.  There are many simple web apps enabling this to create simple video conferencing for **few** participants, where each participant sends audio and video to each of the others.

Such simple setups can easily support turning off receiving audio from one of the peers.

Problem is with larger conferences...

If you need to do meetings with more than 4-6 persons, then it consumes too much bandwidth to send all streams to all participants.  Instead, a central service mixes audio together, and regulates which video streams are forwarded to others.  With such a setup, it becomes more difficult to selectively turn off audio, because the audio inputs are fused together and a single mix is forwarded.

Sorry for those technical details, arguably more relevant for programmers.  My point is that you should beware when looking for applications offering this feature, how it affects *other* qualities: Make sure that the chosen tool is still capable of maintaining a stable and lightweight connection between all the participants for the size of conferences you need.

Janus is one of the most reliable "mixer" backends for WebRTC, capable of handling more than a thousand concurrent connections (spread over multiple rooms - no web browser can handle a single room that large!).  Janus is Free Software and designed for customization, so should be relatively easy for a programmer to adapt for your special needs.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found [Alfaview](https://alfaview.com/en/) which has exactly the feature. Unfortunately it doesn't run from the browser. Also the meeting management is extremely unintuitive. But we will probably go with it.

Also [Discord](https://discord.com/) has the feature and is even available in browser. We did however run into invitation issues and were not able to connect, so we abandoned the tests.

Answer (score 0):

An option, not exactly answering your question but maybe solving the underlying issue with no programming involved, would be to buy a long split cable for audio *output*, and have the two persons in same room use separate microphone but listen to same audio from others.

What me and my partner usually do is even simpler: One of us goes into next room while both attending same conference.
But I guess that's not an option for your scenario.